# LPT hardware in windows 10 pro

Tags: legacy, lpt

I have legacy software that requires a WIBU 25pin D-sub hardware security key plugged into an LPT port. The problem is there aren't any laptops today with an actual 25 pin Printer port. USB/Parallel adapters [none that I have found] will not work as Windows creates a virtual port and calls it LPT[x] however there is Wibu software [along with a driver] that looks at the app, LPT port and the key to compare authorization codes for unlocking the app. the software will only recognize LPT1,2,3 or 4.

So the problem is two fold, a physical 25 pin port connected through USB,and windows to identify the port as a real LPT port to the Wibu software.

I'd give in an buy a new version, which hasn't really changed much at all over the last 20yrs, but the app is god awful expensive and way out of my budget.

Comment: Can you not use a desktop with a PCIe Parallel card?

Comment: A a physical 25 pin port connected through USB,and windows to identify the port as a real LPT  might work if the sucurity key behaves cleany. Many did not. Having a working printer/paralel port thus might not be enough. :(

Comment: If you find a laptop with PCCard (aka PCIe x1) or thunderbolt (PCIe over a wire) then you might use a 1. PCcard to wxternal PCIe, or 2. thurderbolt to extenal PCEi dock adaptor, and plug in a PCIe to real paralele card there. Should work, but it will not be very portable

Comment: Sorry. not pc card. **Express card**.